# Optimization of Google Sheets loading speed

Tags: performance, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

Maybe someone can shed any light, personal experience or reference to official documentation.

Suppose, I have a Google Spreadsheet, which I connected to other Spreadsheets by using IMPORTRANGE. I noticed that my receiving Spreadsheet started loading slower than normal. Are there any tricks for optimizing the loading speed? For example, does it make any difference if I:

- Use IMPORTRANGE less frequently by loading the data (let's say, once) to a separate tab, and then query that tab internally from within the same spreadsheet?

*or*

- Use IMPORTRANGE frequently in multiple cells and run Query for each cell individually, and *avoid* having a large dedicated tab that gets all the info first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `IMPORTRANGE` less frequently by loading the data (let's say, once) to a separate tab, and then query that tab internally from within the same spreadsheet?

definitely the right approach to gain performance speed

Comment: Are you sure? What would be the explanation behind it?

Comment: importrange is heavy class formula so more you have the slower spreadsheet gets

Comment: A sub-question. Some original spreadsheets are really large, so IMPORTRANGE cannot capture them fully because they make it exceed the intended limit. In this case I would have to reduce the number of either imported columns or imported rows and make another IMPORTRANGE or 2 to get it all in one tab. Do you think in cases like this it would still be justified to use IMPORTRANGE several times for pulling all the data to one tab? Or it would be a better idea to query the original sheet in with targeted requests?

Comment: even such scenarios can be solved with "1" importrange formula. to overcome the importrange limit you can stack it in array for example: `={IMOPORTRANGE("id","Sheet1!A1:Z10000"); IMOPORTRANGE("id","Sheet1!A10001:Z20000");IMOPORTRANGE("id","Sheet1!A20001:Z30000")}` or smaller 5k chunks

Comment: Appreciate your input, @player0! Will just wait a little to give others a chance to share opinion, and will select the accepted response.